# Is there a way to save the value of a lookup on a variable in an access macro?

Tags: ms-access

My problem is on the after insert event in a macro of an access table.
I'm trying to create a record after that event is fired, but saving a field of a related table of the inserted record

With SetLocalVar I can save a value of the current record, but some of these values are foreign keys of other tables. I want to get the field of one of the related tables and use it on the creation of the new record

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well I find the solution.

You need to put an alias on the Data Block "LookupRecord" and use that alias as record.

```
SetLocalVar 
    Name = Contact
    Expression = [Contact]

Look Up A Record In Contacts
Where Condition = Contacts.ID = Contact
Alias = C

Create a Record In ContactsLog
    SetField
       Name = "Contact"
       Value = C.ID
    SetField
       Name = "LogDate"
       Value = Date()
```

Comment: Date is a reserved word - it is an intrinsic function. Should not use reserved words as names for anything.